# Create duplicate records based on field value Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an Access table that has the following fields named tReOrder:

- Barcode (Number)
- ReOrder Qty (Number)
- Item Description (Long Text)
- Supplier (Short Text)
- Items per Unit (Short Text)
- Category (Short Text)
- Subcategory (Short Text)

I am trying to create a script or query that will duplicate a record by whatever value is in the ReOrder Qty.

I have tried multiple queries, scripts, spent a few hours googling and cannot find a solution for this.

This is so we can automatically print out enough labels to label what we re-order for our stocks.

Please let me know if more data is needed.

Comment: There are methods to print duplicate record without actually have to create a duplicate record in table. Here is one http://allenbrowne.com/ser-39.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is query that works for me. It uses hidden table MSysObjects which is virtually certain to have enough records.

```
SELECT tReOrder.*
FROM tReOrder, 
   (SELECT DISTINCT [Tens]+[Ones] AS Factor, 10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10) AS Tens, Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10) AS Ones 
    FROM MSysObjects AS Uno, MSysObjects AS Deca) AS F
WHERE F.Factor<[ReOrder Qty]
ORDER BY Barcode;
```

Answer (score 1):

- Create a table called `numbers` with a single field called `id` of **Long Integer** data type:

  [image]
- Populate this table with the integers **0** through **9**:

  [image]
- The following query will then yield the numbers 1-1000:

  ```
  select 100*n100.id+10*n10.id+n1.id+1 as n from numbers n1, numbers n10, numbers n100
  ```

  If your quantity is not likely to exceed 100, this may become:

  ```
  select 10*n10.id+n1.id+1 as n from numbers n1, numbers n10
  ```

  If your quantity is likely to exceed 1000, the following will yield 10000 records:

  ```
  select 1000*n1000.id+100*n100.id+10*n10.id+n1.id+1 as n 
  from numbers n1, numbers n10, numbers n100, numbers n1000
  ```

  (Expand/contract the pattern for the order of magnitude suitable for your data)
- You can now use this table of numbers as part of a [cross join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join) or [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) in order to create a query which will return a given number of records (up to the number of records returned by the above SQL), for each record in another table.

  For your table, such a query might be:

  ```
  select tReOrder.* 
  from tReOrder, 
  (select 100*n100.id+10*n10.id+n1.id+1 as n from numbers n1, numbers n10, numbers n100) t
  where t.n <= tReOrder.[ReOrder Qty]
  ```

  Using this query, if your table were to contain the following records:

  [image]

  You would receive the following result:

  [image]