# MS Access - Repeat Records from a Table by a value in a field

Tags: ms-access, inner-join, cross-join

I would like to repeat Records based on a field value in the corresponding record.  for example: 
banana,.., 6 (i would like to repeat the record for Banana, six times)
Pear, ...., 10 (here I would like to repeat the record for Pear ten times)

Thanks,
F

Comment: Repeat where - in a report? Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54991809/create-duplicate-records-based-on-field-value-access/54992003#54992003

Answer (score 0):

Have a table with numbers from 0 to some more that you expect.

Then use a *Cartesian* query:

```
SELECT 
    tblFruits.Name, 
    tblNumber.Number As Id
FROM 
    tblFruits, 
    tblNumber
WHERE 
    tblNumber.Number Between 1 And tblFruits.Quantity
ORDER BY 
    tblFruits.Name, 
    tblNumber.Number;
```